# Bots spamming forms, but not through website?

Tags: php, forms, email, bots, spam

I've got a website in which there is a simple "Newsletter" signup form.  The form is setup via a Wordpress plugin called "Contact Form 7".  When the form is submitted, I get an e-mail of the persons name and their e-mail address rather than sticking it in a database (as the client has requested).  All of the form submission code is written in PHP.

There's an issue with spam (always 5 e-mails at a time and 4 days apart) in which random-character names are input with legitimate e-mail addresses.

However, the bit that's getting me is that these bots aren't submitting from the form on the actual website.. they're somehow bypassing it and submitting elsewhere.  When a form is submitted via the website, I am e-mailed debugging information regarding the submission.  With these bot/spam submissions, there is no debug information e-mailed to me.

I cannot figure out how they are managing this.  My first thought was that they were accessing the scripts/PHP files directly, so I blocked direct access to the entire contact form root.. but I am still getting the spam.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most bots store your email once you go it. So it doesn't matter what you do, your going to keep getting those emails for a while.

Comment: You can send a POST request without visiting the website...

Comment: Check your webserver logs. See what time the email is sent, check the logs for around that time, find the IP, and then scan the logs for that IP. See what the referrer is, or if they're visiting any other page.

Comment: How are those debug emails being triggered exactly that would allow anyone to submit newsletters signups while at the same time not triggering the debug email?

Comment: To #:

1] I hope this isn't the case.  I'm not sure how they would have access the e-mail addresses in the first place.  You can't directly access them.

2] I have tried to do this via AJAX as well and by accessing the script directly but it does not seem to work.  The html form has an action like '/#wp341-op1' that we can't seem to get to.

3]  I checked the webserver logs, but for some reason new logs aren't there.. only old ones.

4]  I will look into the code and let you know.  I understand most of the code, but it isn't something I could have written myself in any decent amount of time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was coming from an old instance of the website via their previous webhost (see the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to find where the e-mail was coming from via the logs.

It was coming from an old instance of the website via our previous web hoster (where the site was before we moved it).  We have simply deleted that instance.

All should be well!

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution!